# Can't start more than 17 Selenium-webdrivers

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I'm using Selenium with ChromeDriver in a python multithreading environment.
Before multiprocessing starts, each browser-instance is setup. It is possible to start 17 browsers without problem, but if it is more than 17 instances it fails.

Here are the log outputs of the browsers `webdriver.Chrome(service_log_path=self.session_logfile)`:

working instance (instance #17):

```
[…]
[1640642658.135][INFO]: [d95aa29866064789c167e42c4911ed36] RESPONSE SetTimeouts
[1640642658.136][INFO]: [d95aa29866064789c167e42c4911ed36] COMMAND Navigate {
   "url": "https://www.website.com"
}
[1640642658.136][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1640642658.137][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1640642658.417][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1640642659.122][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1640642659.122][INFO]: [d95aa29866064789c167e42c4911ed36] RESPONSE Navigate
[1640642659.127][INFO]: [d95aa29866064789c167e42c4911ed36] COMMAND DeleteAllCookies {

}
[1640642659.127][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1640642659.128][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[…]
```

failing instance (instance #18):

```
[…]
[1640642194.176][INFO]: [9148f58db0e76ea70186f0739b04e677] RESPONSE SetTimeouts
[1640642194.176][INFO]: [9148f58db0e76ea70186f0739b04e677] COMMAND Navigate {
   "url": "https://www.website.com"
}
[1640642194.176][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1640642194.178][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
[1640642194.122][INFO]: [330dd18a9973da505814eddae0cfd97d] COMMAND QuitAll {

}
[1640642194.172][INFO]: [330dd18a9973da505814eddae0cfd97d] RESPONSE QuitAll
```

- The issue is not about multi-threading, since I sequentially start the instances, before I work with parallel processess.
- The machine has more resources, so it is not about a limitation of
  CPU or memory.
- On another machine I can run 30 instances without
  problems.

I tried debugging it, but can't understand why it happens. How can I retrieve more information on why this instance fails/quits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to be using multithreading for Python tests, you may consider using "pytest-xdist" to handle the multiple processes for you: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist. And if you're using Selenium with Python and pytest, there's a framework that may simplify the Selenium test multithreading for you, "SeleniumBase": https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase. It functions as a pytest plugin, so you can use the pytest multi-threading args provided by pytest-xdist, and run all your Selenium Python tests multithreaded as needed. Eg: `pytest -n 20` for 20 parallel threads, assuming your machine has enough memory for that. If your machine doesn't have enough memory for that, then definitely use fewer threads. Spinning up a lot of browser windows can be very memory-intensive.

Comment: thx, your comment guided me thorwards the right path, At first SeleniumBase looked promissing, but tests have the big flaw, they cant dynamically assign tasks. in a main-worker-environment. Achtually what I started using now is a SeleniumGrid.